Tokio Channel isn't Receiving from Streamed Futures
I am making async requests to an API and intending to send the response on a channel to do other things with (like insert into a DB). However, it seems that my Receiver isn't reading from the channel properly. I know the requests are succeeding and data is deserialized properly, but I am seeing no action in my receiver.
Code below using jsonplaceholder free API
use futures::stream::StreamExt;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use tokio::sync::mpsc;

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct Post {
    pub user_id: u16,
    pub id: u16,
    pub title: String,
    pub body: String,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // create iterator that will stream async responses
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let resps = futures::stream::iter(1..)
        .map(|i| {
            let client = &client;
            async move {
                let url = format!("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/{i}");
                client.get(url).send().await
            }
        })
        .buffer_unordered(100);

    let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel::<Post>(50);
    resps
        .for_each(|r| async {
            match r {
                Ok(resp) => {
                    // deserialize response
                    let tx_cloned = tx.clone();
                    let res = resp.json::<Post>().await.unwrap();

                    // send response on the channel
                    let _ = tx_cloned.send(res).await.unwrap();
                }
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("error consuming responses, {e}!");
                }
            }
        })
        .await;

    // consume responses from our channel to do future things with results...
    while let Some(r) = rx.recv().await {
        println!("{:?}", r);
    }
}


Since you don't spawn any task, all your actions are done sequentially, so you try to send an infinite number of queries before you start receiving from the channel.
Try running the for_each() loop in a separate task.

Ideally, I'd like the requests to be done sequentially, but send to channel as each are completed and allow the Receiver channel to do work while the requests are being made.

I modified the code to spawn in another task and it did work, but still confused on why its not receiving from the channel sine I await the prior expression. Is it because it is all running in the same thread unless I tokio::spawn(async {})?

@Coldchain9 rather than threads you should talk about tasks with tokio because it may move one task from one thread to another, but all the code in a single task will be executed sequentially.
Your requirement of only sending a new request once a reply has been received is already guaranted by the way stream::iter works. If you only want to send the next query when it has been fully processed, don't use a channel and process the reply inside the loop.

Thanks for clarifying. The idea of the channel is to do separate async work (like sending the response to a database while the stream is processing data). At least, that was my intent.
